# Post an array in flutter

Tags: flutter, http, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test

i want to post this array to the server
[
{
"productID" : 20203,
"productQuantity" : 1,
"productPrice": 200
},
{
"productitemID" : 2483,
"productQuantity" : 1,
"productPrice": 400
}
]

```
Future<String> postorder(productorder_post post) async {

  String urlss = "https://SHOP.NOW.com/api/ORDER";




  Map<String,String> headers = {   HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json'
  };
  http.Response response = await http.post(urlss,headers: {
    "content-type": "application/json",
  }, body: json.encode(post.toJson()));

  if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 400) {
    String responseBody = response.body;


    print(responseBody);
   

  } else {
    throw Exception(response.statusCode);
  }
}
```

postorder(new productorder_post(itemID: 88,quantity: 8,price: 44));

```
class productorder_post {
  int itemID;
  int quantity;
  int price;

  productorder_post({this.itemID, this.quantity, this.price});

  productorder_post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    itemID = json['itemID'];
    quantity = json['Quantity'];
    price = json['Price'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['itemID'] = this.itemID;
    data['Quantity'] = this.quantity;
    data['Price'] = this.price;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your service for the "server"?

Comment: E/flutter (10647): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Exception: 405

Comment: If you're recieveing a [405 error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405) when trying to POST. Basically, your server isn't accepting POST requests.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your server works correct, a possible problem could be that you are sending integers. As far is I know the http package in flutter can't send integers in the json body. You'll have to parse them to strings... At least that's what I would try.